# how can i storage and connect access database/ file using Windows application vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, connection, cloud

i have Windows application application developed on vb.net & Access, how can i place access database/file on cloud/internet and install application on local computer like PC and laptop then connect to access database/file...
I am entirely new to this stuff so I did some search for tutorials. Everything that I found was very technical (at least on my pov) and are very hard to follow especially for beginners like me.

Comment: That is a very poor choice. Access is not really designed to be used that way.

Comment: please give me advise ... what is the good choice / combination ... and how i can do this ... application is small but user from same organisation will use it from different location and from different pc/Laptops .... need your help .. im only familiar with vb.net , access and oracle database.

Comment: SO is not a place to get general advise on which database to use. I'm just telling you that the question you asked is the wrong question and that you should do some research on databases to find the right question.